# Total monthly Interest formula

Tags: javascript, math, formula

Im trying to display the value of the total interest paid once the value hits zero. So basically all interest per month added together as a final value. Then I need to display the value of monthly interest in percent. I cannot figure out the formula for this. Here is the example of how it should look http://snag.gy/9vzGi.jpg

```
function buildResults() {

    var amount = parseFloat(document.getElementById("loanAmt").value );
    var monthly = parseInt(document.getElementById("monthlyPay").value );
    var rate = parseFloat(document.getElementById("intRte").value );



    rate = rate / 100 / 12;

    var msg = "<table id='tablefont' border='3' width='65%'>";
    msg += "<tr>";
    msg += "<td>Month</td>";
    msg += "<td>Principal Paid</td>";
    msg += "<td>Interest Paid</td>";
    msg += "<td>Loan Balance</td>";
    msg += "</tr>";



    newPrincipal=amount;
    var m = 1;   //months

    while ( amount > 0 ) {
        var interest = amount * rate;
        var principal = monthly - interest;

        if (principal > amount) {
            principal = amount;
            amount = 0.0;
        } else {
            amount -= principal;
        }
        var sum = (interest.toFixed(2) + m);

        msg += "<tr><td align='left' bgcolor='pink'>"+m+"</td> \
                <td align='left' bgcolor='pink'>$"+fixVal(principal,0,2,' ')+"</td> \
                <td align='left' bgcolor='pink'>$"+fixVal(interest,0,2,' ')+"</td> \
                <td align='left' bgcolor='pink'>$"+fixVal(amount,0,2,' ')+"</td></tr>";

        m++;

    }

    var msg2 = "";
    msg2 += "Loan Amount: $" + document.getElementById("loanAmt").value + "<br>";
    msg2 += "Annual Interest: " + document.getElementById("intRte").value + "%" +"<br>";
    msg2 += "Monthly Payment: $" + document.getElementById("monthlyPay").value + "<br>";
    msg2 += "Monthly Interest:  " + fixVal(interest,0,2,' ') +"<br>";
    msg2 += "Months to pay off loan: " + (m-1) +"<br>";
    msg2 += "Total Interest Paid: $" + sum + "<br>";


    msg += "</table>";



    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = msg;
    document.getElementById("overview").innerHTML = msg2;


}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Look at the example link. I cannot seem to figure out the formula for displaying the value of total interest paid. To the left where it says 'Total Interest Paid: $43.71' I think I have to find a formula that adds all of the interest together but can't seem to get it.

Comment: I don't see what the problem is.  That "Total Interest Paid" is equal to the sum of the Interest Paid column in your table.

Comment: Thats the example of how it should look. My version just displays the final interest value.

Comment: Oh I see.  In your loop, just sum the interests calculated in another variable.

Comment: I tried that var sum = interest + m (#of months) but it doesnt work. What could be the correct way to add all interests together? What Im trying to do is add them based on the amount of months it takes to pay off, Im def doing something wrong

Comment: Sounds like an annuity calculator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sum your interests in a loop.  Make sure the variable is outside the while loop, or it will go out of scope.

```
var sumInterest = 0;
while ( amount > 0 ) {
    var interest = amount * rate;
    sumInterest += interest;
    var principal = monthly - interest;
    //rest of code here
```

Comment: Nice, easy enough solution. I was putting variable within loop too. Thanks. Only problem now is that the number isnt rounded 2 places

Comment: Ah, that is easy.  `Math.round(sumInterest*100)/100;`  This will get rid of all decimal places after the first two to be rounded away.

Comment: At the end of your loop, after the closing brace. put `sumInterest = Math.round(sumInterest*100)/100;`

Comment: Perfect. I greatly appreciate your help. I hope one day I can memorize everything as you have. Take care

Comment: No problem.  It just takes time and practice.  Good luck!